# Migrate windows 7 network drive to Ubuntu 11.10 for use as a file server

Tags: networking, server, windows-7, samba, migration

On my network (7 computers with windows 7 Pro) one of the computers has a partitioned HDD and sharing that partition as a network drive for all other users to access.
All other computers have a that drive mapped to Z:

I want to migrate the data from the shared drive to a new computer with Ubuntu 11.10 and use Samba to share files with the windows computers, which isn't too complicated, but now my question arises.

What must I watch out for so all linked documents, programs, etc. continue to work?

There are lots of excel files with cells linked to other excel files (`='Z:\Folder\Anotherfolder\[File.xls]Sheet2'!F3` )

I have already had a look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows/TransferringFilesAndSettings) link, but it's more for desktop migration...

I would also appreciate your opinion on weather to use Ubuntu or Ubuntu Server, taking notice that the network has only 7 computers, the only purpose is to share files/folders and maybe backup.

Comment: I've done some googling... came up with this:
http://archive.thekks.net/456

Seems that I can map the share to Z: without problems..

Comment: I think there is no need for another answer, but here's a tip that could spare you some trouble: During the Ubuntu Setup, make sure to set the computer name as it was under Windows (upper- or lowercase doesn't matter) because then you don't have to re-mount the network drive on the computers which use the shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

A Samba file server would work great for this. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "linked", but you shouldn't have any problems as long as you retain the same share directory tree as you had on windows, and as long as the programs are looking for the Z:\ drive (or whatever drive letter you map the share as) and not the specific IP Address or Domain Name of the Windows machine.

[Here is the official Ubuntu documentation to setup a Samba File Server.](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html)
[Here is the advanced guide that shows you how to setup authentication.](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileprint-security.html)